# Running cmd programmatically only returns some outputs

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm running a CMD in c# programmatically and everything works fine, it will run whatever command I input but when I ask to return the output to the console, only some commands output gets returned.

For example if I write "ipconfig" as the command, it will return my ip info but if I write "/ipconfig", it will just return "/ipconfig" as appose to "/ipconfig is not recognized as an interal ..." you get the idea. I also tried it with deleting files, the file deletes just fine but if the file doesnt exist, it should output "could not find file" like it does it normal cmd. It seems it only gives me the output of a command thats runs and not one that doesnt even though I read the cmd till the end of anything it outputs. If this is the case is there anyway to get around this?

Code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string command = "/ipconfig";
        string root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        Console.WriteLine(Command(command, root));
    }

    public string Command(string command, string directory)
    {
        string commandOutput;

        commandOutput = DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + command + Environment.NewLine;

        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directory;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();

        commandOutput += proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        return commandOutput;
    }
```

Comment: you could also force `cmd`  to redirect ErrorOutput to StandardOutput: `"/c " + command 2>&1`  ( `2>&1` means "Write STDERR to the same destination as STDOUT") See [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure cmd.exe will write that to standard error, not standard output.  If that is the case, you'll need to use `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` to get the error message.

Comment: ah that makes sense, its outputting everything now, thanks :)